Stored procedure with & without parameter
If I have a stored procedure with parameters in SQL Server & we want to call that stored procedure from .NET code without parameter, it will throw an error. How to handle this situation to avoid error?

You stored procedure must have default values for those parameters if you want to call without parameters. Here is an example with SQL Server stored procedures:
CREATE PROCEDURE [YourProcedureName]
(
    @Parameter1 INT = NULL, -- setting NULL as the default value
    @Parameter2 NVARCHAR(50) = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
   -- Your code goes here.
END


Setting null value will not throw an error in dot net code? Is there any other way not to add parameters in dot net code still it works?

It should not throw error in .NET code, but your stored procedure should have logic to handle the default values. Btw default values don't have to be nulls, I just put nulls in my example, you can put anything you want to use as defaults.
